# Using the JavaScript regular expression flavour, how to match a specific tag only when inside another specific tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match only the `<br>` tags that are inside the `<main>` tag and not all of them:

[image]

Is it possible to do it with a JS regex? I'm trying to do a find and replace (with regex) in all files in a project.

Here's the raw text:

```
<br>
<main>
    <input>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <etc>
</main>
```

Comment: i think it will be better to first capture the `main` tag part and then `br` inside it..

Comment: also, it will be better to use html parser instead of regex unless you are bound to use it

Comment: Why RegEx, though? You can match the tags themselves with `document.querySelector("main br")` and possibly the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: Don't. [Just don't.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/615754)

Comment: It has to be regex because I'm trying to do a find and replace (with regex) in all files in a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DOM` is always better for parsing HTML text. However if for reason you cannot use `DOM` here is a regex solution to match all `<br>` tags between `<main>` and `</main>`.

```
/<\s*br\s*\/?>(?=.*?(?:(?!<main>)[\s\S])*?<\/main>)/gi
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
<\s*br\s*\/?>   # matches <br> or <br />
(?=             # start of lookahead
  .*?           # any arbitrary text, lazy
  (?:           # start of non-capturing group
     (?!        # start of negative lookahead
       <main>   # literal text <main>
     )          # end of negative lookahead   
     [\s\S]*?   # match 0 or more of any char including newline, lazy
  )             # end of non-capturing group
  <\/main>      # match </main>
)               # end of lookahead
/gi             # make it global ignore case match
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH5eV4/1)

Answer (score 0):

Created codepen URL for capturing only the BR elements with MAIN using

```
 document.body.childNodes
```

codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MeybzK

First got all the childNodes of Body and then MAIN and filtered BR tags from that

Hope this is helpful for you

```
        function allTags() {
        var c = document.body.childNodes;
        //console.log(c);
        var txt = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i].nodeName == "MAIN") {
                // alert(c[i].childNodes.length )
                for (j = 0; j < c[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
                    //alert(c[i].childNodes[j].nodeName);
                    if (c[i].childNodes[j].nodeName == "BR") {
                        txt = txt + c[i].childNodes[j];
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        console.log(txt);

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
```

HTML:

```
          <p>11</p><br>
      <main>
          <br>
          <div>q1111</div><br>
      </main>

      <button onclick="allTags()">Tags</button>
      <div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Please. Keep all the necessary code within your answer.

Comment: sure Roko... I just left the gist of code which i have used to achieve ..I will update it now :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented and I always say, don't use regexes to parse HTML. And yes, you can use the DOM to replace elements. It won't be quite as compact (and unreadable) as a regex but I think this is still quite short :

```
for(let br of document.querySelector('main br'))
  br.parentNode.replaceChild(br, document.createElement('span'))
```

(assuming you wanted to replace `<br>`s with another Element. Deleting or replacing with text would be just as easy.)